# Jquery Validation:Print zero in textbox when submit button clicked using class

Tags: jquery, validation

```
input name="currency1" class="currency"

input name="currency2" class="currency"

input name="weight1" class="weight"

input name="weight2" class="weight"


function init(){

    var ZERO = 0;
    var currency= $(".currency").val();

    if(currency== '' || currency.length == 0){
        $(".currency").val(ZERO.toFixed(2));
    }
    else if(currency!= '' || currency.length != 0){
        $(".currency").val();
    }

}
```

when currency1 is fill it should not change but when it is empty it should print zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use '===' for comparing instead of '==' ([Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript))

Try this,

```
(function(){

    var ZERO = 0;
    var currency= $(".currency").val();

    if(currency=== '' || currency.length === 0){
        $(".currency").val(ZERO.toFixed(2));
    }
    else if(currency!== '' || currency.length !== 0){
        $(".currency").val();
    }

}());
```

[Demo Here...](http://jsfiddle.net/flowerking/XVHSP/)